# How to mass insert keys in redis running as pod in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, redis

I have referred to https://redis.io/topics/mass-insert and tried the Luke protocol,
and did

```
cat data.txt | redis-cli -a <pass> -h <events-k8s-service> --pipe-timeout 100 > /dev/null
```

The redirection to /dev/null is to ignore the replies. The CLIENT REPLY of redis can't serve its purpose here from CLI and it may turn into a blocking command.

The data.txt has around 18 Million records/commands like

```
SELECT 1
SET key1 '"field1":"val1","field2":"val2","field3":"val3","field4":"val4","field5":val5,"field6":val6'
SET key2 '"field1":"val1","field2":"val2","field3":"val3","field4":"val4","field5":val5,"field6":val6'
.
.
.
```

This command is executed from a cronJob which execs into the redis pod, and **executes the above command from within the pod**, to understand the footprint, **the redis pod had no resources limit** and following are the observation:

```
Keys loaded: 18147292
Time taken: ~31 minutes
Peak CPU:  2063 m 
Peak Memory:  4745 Mi
```

The resources consumed are way too high and the time taken is too long.

The questions:

1. How do we load mass load data of the order 50 Million keys using redis pipe, is there an alternate approach to this problem ?
2. Is there a golang/python library that does the same mass loading efficiently(less time , little footprint of mem and cpu) ?
3. Do we need to fine tune redis here ?

The help is appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: in this https://redis.io/topics/mass-insert , it says to use `--pipe` mode, however in your input you only specified `--pipe-timeout 100` and no `--pipe`. just wondering..no expert.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `redis-cli` inside the pod to move the millions of key into **Redis** POD won't be able to handle it.

Also, you have not specified any resources that you are giving to Redis however it's a memory store so it will be better to give proper memory to redis 2-3 GB depends on usegae.

You can try out the **Redis-riot** : https://github.com/redis-developer/riot

to add data into the Redis.

There is also good video across loading the Big foot data into the redis : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TqTg6RijfaU

> Do we need to fine tune redis here.

Increase the memory for redis if it's getting **OOMkilled**.